# Watir webdriver and extjs finding element

Tags: javascript, ruby, extjs, selenium, watir

I am doing an acceptance test using watir-webdriver using ruby
I wanna ask if watir webdriver is support for ExtJs or not?
I am trying to find element that generated dynamically by ExtJS. I am trying doing some thing like

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
#Some step go to page
@cbo = @browser.execute_script "return Ext.getCmp('cboCategory')"
```

but It didn't work
Please give me some advises.
Thank you.

Comment: It would help to be more specific about what you are trying to do - ie give an actual example. ExtJS has quite a number of features, which means a general response might not be useful. If your page is not available to the public, then consider giving an example that does not work from the [ExtJS webpage](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExtJS pages are hard to test, especially on finding elements.

Here are some of the tips I consider useful:

- Don't ever use dynamically generated IDs. like `(:id, 'ext-gen1302')`
- Don't ever use absolute/meaningless XPath, like `//div[4]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div/div/span[2]/span`
- Take advantage of meaningful auto-generated partial ids and class names.

  For example, [this](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#array-grid) ExtJS grid example: `(:css, '.x-grid-view .x-grid-table')` would be handy. If there are multiple of grids, try index them or locate the identifiable ancestor, like `(:css, '#something-meaningful .x-grid-view .x-grid-table')`.
- Create meaningful class names in the source code. ExtJS provides `cls` and `tdCls` for custom class names, so you can add `cls:'testing-cmb-category'` in your source code, and get it by `(:css, '.x-panel .testing-cmb-category')`.

Other answers I made on this topic:

- [How to find unique selectors for elements on pages with ExtJS for use with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18047730/1177636)
- [How to click on elements in ExtJS using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061747/1177636)
- [Using class names in Watir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840310/1177636)
- [how to click on checkboxes on a pop-up window which doesn't have name, label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17308416/1177636)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. It is help me so much